# golang using functools.partial or similar to accomplish wrapping other functions

Tags: go

(new to golang)

Let's say I have two functions that interact with an API underneath and I'd like to wrap both with retries but these two functions have different input params.

In Python I would use `functools.partial` to create a partial func object and pass that in

```
from functools import partial

def api_1(a, b, c):
  print(a, b, c)
  return true
  
def api_2(x, y):
  print(x, y)
  return true

def with_retries(func) {
  retries = 0
  while retries < 3:
    err = func()
    if not err:
      break
    retries += 1
}

def main():
  with_retries(partial(api_1, 1, 2, 3))
  with_retries(partial(api_2, 'x', 'y'))
```

Using the simple example above, how could I do something similar in golang? I looked at the `functools.Partial` package function but that one seems like it does not allow to pass in all of the parameters when creating a partial?

Is there a completely different pattern in golang to accomplish this retry pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand `functools.Partial` correctly, it allows you to curry functions.

In Go you can use closures to curry functions:

```golang
func Add(x,y int) int {
  return x+y
}
// Curries Add to yield a function that adds 4
func Add4(y int) int {
  return Add(4,y)
}
```

Go supports first-class functions, so you can pass functions as variables. In this case we create a function `Do` that accepts (a) any function that's `int-->int` and (b) an `int` and returns the result of applying the function to the `int`:

```golang
func Do(f func(int) int, y int) int {
    return f(y)
}
```

And, because `Do` only needs `int-->int` we can use e.g. `Neg` too per:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func Add(x, y int) int {
    return x + y
}
func Add4(y int) int {
    return Add(4, y)
}

func Neg(x int) int {
    return -x
}

func Do(f func(int) int, y int) int {
    return f(y)
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(Add4(6))
    fmt.Println(Do(Add4, 6))
    fmt.Println(Do(Neg, 6))
}
```

See: https://go.dev/play/p/4ZkIpvYTxC0

Comment: thanks, this is a good example on how to use Partial, so I think this confirms that it wouldn't apply to what I'm trying to do. I want to be able to "freeze" the function call and pass that in as an object to a retries function (like the python example)

Comment: Yes, you can freeze the function call. You'd define a function (`f`) that takes zero parameters that invokes/returns e.g. `api_1(1,2,4)`. You could define the equivalent `with_retries` to take a zero parameter function and pass `f` to it. Make sense?

Comment: You could use anonymous functions for the wrapping functions. I didn't specify that to keep the answer simpler.

Comment: See: https://go.dev/play/p/QaxncWj_0tB

Comment: pretty new to go so it takes a bit to digest, thank you for sharing a working example! I think it is pretty close to what I want from a quick look, I'm going to spend a bit playing with it and I'll accept the answer then. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck. We're all new to everything sometime.