# Generic function to wrap similar methods of different structs

Tags: go, generics

I'm working on a GOLANG problem and I'm not sure how to address it (or even if there is a good way to address it). I have a bunch of different structs that I have to use from a set of third party packages. I do not have any control over changes in them. This skeleton code is similar to what I'm trying to do in my production code.

```
package main

import "fmt"

// I cannot change these types
type Thing1Param struct{}

func (i Thing1Param) MayFail() (*Thing1Return, error) {
    var thing1Return Thing1Return
    var err error
    var success bool

    if success {
        return &thing1Return, nil
    } else {
        return nil, err
    }
}

type Thing1Return struct{}

type Thing2Param struct{}

func (i Thing2Param) MayFail() (*Thing2Return, error) {
    var thing2Return Thing2Return
    var err error
    var success bool

    if success {
        return &thing2Return, nil
    } else {
        return nil, err
    }
}

type Thing2Return struct{}

// I can change this stuff
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello World")
}

func MayFailWithRetry[P Thing1Param | Thing2Param, R Thing1Return | Thing2Return](param P) (R, error) {
    var rtn R
    var err error

    for { // replace with a Exponential backoff loop that will fail at some point
        rtn, err = param.MayFail()
        if err != nil {
            // handle error then retry
            continue
        } else {
            break
        }

    }

    return rtn, err
}
```

As you can see, there are many different `ThingXParams` that all contain a method called `MayFail()` that returns a pointer to `ThingXReturn` and an `error`. What I need to do is create an exponential backoff so that when these functions fail, they are retried until they get success. Unfortunately, since there are many different `Thing`s whose `MayFail()` functions return pointers to different types, I am having difficulty getting a generic function to work.

I am trying to avoid having to duplicate the logic of the `MayFailWithRetry()` function for every `Thing` that needs it and would rather have one function that takes a `ThingXParam` type and returns a `ThingXReturn` pointer and an `error` no matter what `X` is. Unfortunately, when I implement the code above, I get an error that `param.MayFail is undefined (type P has no field or method MayFail)`.

Because the function signatures are different, I don't think I can do this with an interface, and though I think it should work with generics, I can't seem to figure out how to do so. My Googling has been ineffective up to this point.

Is it possible to solve this problem, or am I stuck writing separate ExponentialBackoff functions for all different types? If it is possible, how would you approach the problem?

My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75025616/golang-using-functools-partial-or-similar-to-accomplish-wrapping-other-functions), but it is different because the return types for the wrapped function are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass methods ([method values](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_values)) into your generic function and parametrize the return type.

> The method value `x.M` is a function value that is callable with the same arguments as a method call of `x.M`. The expression `x` is evaluated and saved during the evaluation of the method value; the saved copy is then used as the receiver in any calls, which may be executed later.

You can model your `MayFail` methods as follows:

```
type Failable[T any] func() (*T, error)
```

<sup>it's not necessary to use a named type here, but it makes the code clearer.</sup>

Then declare the function with the retry logic as accepting arguments of `Failable[T]` type:

```
func MayFailWithRetry[R any](mayFail Failable[R]) (*R, error) {
    rtn, err = mayFail()
    // ...
    return rtn, err
}
```

Within this function, the argument `mayFail` is simply a function that returns `(*R, error)`. Based on the above quote from the language spec, this fits the signature of any `MayFail` method *called on a specific instance* of a `ThingXParams` struct. I named the type parameter `R` to make it clear it's a return type.

Then you call `MayFailWithRetry` with a **method value** as argument. Notice the lack of parenthesis after the method name `MayFail`:

```
func main() {
    t1 := Thing1Param{}
    r1, err := MayFailWithRetry(t1.MayFail)
    // r1 is a *Thing1Return

    t2 := Thing2Param{}
    r2, err := MayFailWithRetry(t2.MayFail)
    // r2 is a *Thing2Return
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/I7ry7FJqLes